# Why is Jquery UI Datepicker not making dates unavailable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm developing a datepicker that will allow an administrator to choose dates that holiday makers will be staying at her property, and then store that data in a database. I then want to update a datepicker that potential customers will see with the unavailable dates greyed out.

I've managed to retrieve the data from my database and pass it via JSON into a JS variable but I'm having no luck greying it out with the beforeShowDay method. My console.log on the datesToBlock var showed the following info:

```
Object {fromDate: "2014-02-28", toDate: "2014-02-23"}
```

---

And my code so far.

```
var datesToBlock = <?php echo json_encode($unavailableDates); ?>;


  $(function() {
      var unavailableDates = ["false","","not available"]; 
      $( "#fromDatepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        beforeShowDay: function(datesToBlock) {
          return unavailableDates;
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Uhm, why is the first variable named the same as the argument for the beforeShowDay callback? Why are you passing back an array that doesn't contain dates, just false, an empty string and "not available"? I don't really get this at all, and a Fiddle should be easy enough to set up for this.

Comment: Simplify: first remove the beforeShowDay function and get the basic functionally to work.  You have jQuery and jQuery UI included...right?

Comment: @adeneo 

```beforeShowDayType: Function( Date date )

Default: null
A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
[0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
[1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
[2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.
```

Comment: @KevinB the datepicker is displaying. I've changed the title to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: Well, I really don't get it, and I really don't think you are getting it either? I guess what you're trying to do is this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/sY6z7/1/**